# How to add elevation data to tif to create DEM (SRTM satellite data)

Tags: coordinate-system, dem, geotiff-tiff, elevation, srtm

I have a .tif created from the SRTM satellite data. The tif should already be DEM data as it was collected from the SRTM satellite.

When I open the tif in ArcGIS, I don't see any height or z data, nor any way to add it.
What am I missing here? I tried to add XY data as you would with a shapefile, but that option is not available for this tif. I tried "Project Raster" and "Define projection" but again, there is no option to project to a vertical coordinate system.

Where is the Z data in this tif??

The tif was downloaded with kml files--which I think are "hillside shade" --is the Z data somehow in the kml layer?

Edit:
This is a .tif from the SRTM dataset. It's distributed by USGS. 
Further information about it:

*"SRTM GL1 (30m Ellipsoidal) is a version of the popular Shuttle Radar Topography Mission dataset where elevation values are WGS84 ellipsoidal height as opposed to the standard orthometric, or geoid-referenced, elevation. OpenTopography constructed this dataset by subtracting the EGM96 geoid model from the standard SRTM GL1 data. This dataset was produced primarily to support the InSAR community and their need for ellipsoidal referenced DEMs for terrain correction"*

XY Coordinate system: WGS 1984
Vertical Coordinate system:  *there is none*

Raster information:

Number of bands: 1

Format: TIFF

Statistics

Band 1: 
Min -56

Max 22768

Mean 208

Std dev 373

Comment: The pixel values are the elevation / Z values. Unless you have a derived product. Please  [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/363733/edit) your question to answer the following - Where did you get this TIFF? Has any processing been done to it? What are the TIFF details (CRS, pixel size, band count, band statistics)?

Comment: I mean, I realize that after calculating statistics there is information about each pixel. But how can I use this information? I can't create a TIN or project the tif, like I can with a shapefile containing Z data. Shoudl I create a table?

Comment: Does the .tif file have bounds/georeferencing information? SRTM data is often distributed as hgt files where the bounds are stored in the filename like `N20E123` rather than in the file, if the tif was naively converted from that format may need to georeference your data.